# How to set a real number as a blank in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a list of 500 numbers, and wanted to take a mean of every 10 numbers in that, successively, and thus create an output file with 50 data points. Then it will be further plotted.

But suppose in an interval of 10 all the 10 data are missing, i.e. blank, then I should be able to write correspondingly blank in the output file. But, if my output array is of real type, then I cannot write it as a blank character.

I even tried to create the output array as character type, but, it's showing problem that it cannot write real values to a character type variable.

My question has two points:-

1. Is there any way that I can store the real variable as blank?
2. or, How to store real values to character type variable?

I tried the following code to test :-

```
real r
r=''
write(*,*) r
```

The output 'r' shows some real value instead.

And for someone suggesting that I should write the output directly to file, I must tell, that I need that output array necessarily for further procedures upon it.

Answer (score 2):

A Fortran real number is always a number, most often in the IEEE floating point format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 . There are some special values, such as not-a-number (NaN) and +-infinity (+Inf, -Inf) but they won't be output as a blank either.

If I understand it correctly, you basically want some sort of an [Option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type).

You must either check whether the number contains this special value and output a blank if that is the case

```
  if (ieee_is_nan(r)) then
    write(*,*)
  else
    write (*,*) r
  end if
```

or you would have to use some more complicated type

```
  type my_type
    real value
    logical is_blank =.false.
  end type
```

or you would have to use an allocatable real variable and liave it not allocated if it is blank

```
  if (.not. allocated(r)) then
    write(*,*)
  else
    write (*,*) r
  end if
```